# Separate MVC and webAPI controller route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-web-api

I have created a WebApi project, which has multiple WebApi controllers. As per my requirement I have to add an MVC controller to my WebApi project. My client side code is making an ajax request to that MVC controller with `{ControllerName/ActionMethodName}`. I have multiple routes in my `global.asax` file:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ActionRoute",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Below is my `ReportServiceBaseController`:

```
protected virtual ReportServiceBase CreateReportService(); 

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult LoadDocumentInfo(LoadDocumentInfoRequest request);

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult LoadDocumentMapInfo(LoadDocumentMapInfoRequest request);

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult LoadDocumentMapInfoFull(LoadDocumentMapInfoFullRequest request);

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult LoadPageInfo(LoadPageInfoRequest request);
```

I am inheriting that controller in a `ReportService` controller:

```
public class ReportServiceController : ReportServiceBaseController
{
    protected override PerpetuumSoft.Reporting.WebViewer.Server.ReportServiceBase   CreateReportService()
    {
        return new ServiceClass();
    }

}
```

The client side URL which is making the request:

> "http://" + hostName + "/ReportService/LoadDocumentInfo"

I think the WebApi route is suppressing the MVC Controller route. How can I separate the MVC Controller route from the WebApi route?

Comment: Can you show us the request URL for which you think the route is suppressed (in general they way the routes are created is preventing suppressing through the `api` part in the URL).

Comment: I have edited question with code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new config class of WebApi, `ApiRouteConfig.cs`, within `App_Start`.

```
namespace Mvc4App
{
    public class ApiRouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "ActionRoute",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }    
}
```

Then, edit `Global.asax.cs`, to call `ApiRouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have done same thing as explain by you.But still it is not working.First I have register API route then MapRoute.If I register MapRoute first then I was not able to call API methods.Please help.